# how to animated sprite for cocos2d in ccz format

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

According to [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2361/how-to-create-and-optimize-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d-with-texture-packer-and-pixel-formats) PVR images seem to be the best format for iOS sprites.  However after creating a sprite sheet with Texturepacker and exporting out to this format I cannot get the animation to work in cocos2d.
According to the documentation [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3asprites) I should be using

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"LuckyCompiled.plist"];
```

But neither the tutorial nor the documentation explain how to do animation, except for [this](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aanimation).   Which is what the code below is based on.
But this only places the base image onto the layer and does not animate.

```
CCSprite *sprite = [[CCSprite alloc]init];
    sprite.position = ccp(player.contentSize.width/2+40, winSize.height/2+40);
    // Obtain the shared instance of the cache
    CCSpriteFrameCache *cache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];

   // load the frames
   [cache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"LuckyCompiled.plist"];

   // It loads the frame named "frame1.png".
    // IMPORTANT: It doesn't load the image "frame1.png". "frama1.png" is a just the name of the frame
    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [cache spriteFrameByName:@"lucky1.png"];
                                 [sprite setDisplayFrame:frame];
    [self addChild:sprite];

    NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

    CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"lucky%d.png",i]];
            [animFrames addObject:frame];
        }
    NSLog(@"animaframes %@",animFrames);
        CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:[NSArray arrayWithArray:animFrames]];

    [sprite runAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation]];
```

---

Answer:

Needed to have a delay otherwise animation wasnt noticeable

```
[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:[NSArray arrayWithArray:animFrames]];
```

should have been (also no need to make is nsarray, mutable is fine)

```
[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:0.1f];
```

Comment: Did you add the Sprite Sheet to your project?

Comment: yes.  like i said too the sprite does show (the correct image) it just doesnt animate at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the code that I tried, it works fine.

```
CCSpriteFrameCache *frameCache = [CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache];
        [frameCache addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"walkFrames.plist"];

        player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"f1.png"];
        NSMutableArray *frames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            NSString *file = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"f%d.png", i];
            CCSpriteFrame *frame = [frameCache spriteFrameByName:file];
            [frames addObject:frame];
        }
        CCAnimation *walkAnim =[CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:frames delay:0.1f];
        CCAnimate *animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim];
        CCRepeatForever *rep = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];
        player.position = ccp(23, 285);
        [player runAction:rep];

        [self addChild:player];
```

Comment: it was the delay that caused it to "look" like it wasn't animating but apparently was just going to fast

Comment: oh, yeah, you have used `animationWithSpriteFrames:` method of `CCAnimation` not `animationWithSpriteFrames:delay`in your code. When you use `animationWithSpriteFrames:` method, you should then specify the delay by setting `delayPerUnit` property of `CCAnimation` like this: `animation.delayPerUnit = 0.1f;`